# Does Question Unabanning process take forever?

Tags: support, post-ban

Here's [My Profile](https://askubuntu.com/users/178235/yousefs?tab=reputation), I can't post any question and I’m banned because I had some downvotes. Yes I had some downvotes, but I have earned around 50 Reputation since the last downvote.

I know the process is automatically, but, how much time it takes to get unbanned? How many reputations I need? If it really takes forever than I’ll just forget that I signed up to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SE hasn't released any information on how exactly the process works, but we know that it takes negative scored, zero scored and deleted questions and answers in consideration.

Out of 44 answers you have 3 with a positive score and 3 accepts. Out of 13 questions you have 1 with a positive score. You need to prove to the system that you can ask *good* questions and post *good* answers, consistently.

If you are willing to put some continued effort into it, you should not find it hard to lift the ban.

Good luck and keep going!

Comment: Oh, didn't knew that Zero scored and deleted Q&A Are in Consideration. damn it